# List annotated git tags with specific pattern without cloning or pulling

Tags: git

Is it possible to list annotated tags with a specific pattern without cloning or pulling the entire repository from Git?

What I want to do is essentially this:

```
git tag -l "*pattern*" | sort -r
```

without cloning the repo.

I'm aware that you can use `ls-remote` to list tags, i.e.

```
git ls-remote --tags git://github.com/git/git.git
```

but this doesn't seem to give me the option to search for `*pattern*` if I'm not mistaken.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: No, you either have to fetch or filter the output of `ls-remote` manually.

Comment: Hi Lasse, I believe you are wrong, unless I misunderstood the question. Please see my answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is possible.
You can use `git ls-remote <remote> --tags <pattern>` to match.

For instance:

`git ls-remote <remote> --tags **/v*.0
e8b29c3c46a59dc59e2a3b22c253860c23a9ea39        refs/tags/v1.0.0`

vs.

`git ls-remote <remote> --tags **/v*.10`

In a repository where the tag `refs/tags/v1.0.0` exists.

You can look at the [ls-remote documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-remote.html)

Answer (score 0):

The following command gives the list of last **number** of tags matching the **pattern**

```
git tag --sort=-version:refname --list '<pattern>' | head -n <number>
```